# .htaccess redirection for web service failing with error: Too many redirects occurring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an issue with correctly modifying my .htaccess file.
The goal is to implement a web service on my server to handle Apple's passkit requests.

This works perfect.. almost. Because my intention was, that when a user is typing: www.domain.com he should be directed to www.domain.com/index.php. This would be the usual index.php I would like him to see, when accessing my website.

And when Apples Server is trying to send requests to my web service, they should be redirected to the subfolder /server/index.php. This works fine, when calling www.domain.com
But when calling any different URL, that should be redirected, I get an error:
"Too many redirects occurring.."

I expected the redirection to /server/index.php

How do I have to modify my config file correctly?
I configured the file as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If file with specified name does not exist, procede to rewrite rule below
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # if request = root
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php
    # else
    RewriteRule !^/?(index\.php)$ www.medifaktor.de/server/index.php [R=301]

    # Check for HTTP Header Authorization and if so, import it as a server environment variable into PHP
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rule is wrong since it is checking for not equal to `/index.php` and redirecting to `/server/index.php`.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If file with specified name does not exist, procede to rewrite rule below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request = root
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php
# else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^/?(server/index\.php)$ /server/index.php [NC,L]

# Check for HTTP Header Authorization and if so, import it as a server environment variable into PHP
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you anubhava! I just tried what you suggested and it works fine. But now something interesting is happening. To test if the URL with the components that don't physically exist will be redirected correcty, I tried the following:

```
<?php

require_once("lib.php");

// get the request parameters out of the request URL
$requestURL = (($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] != "") ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptPath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$requestURL = str_replace($scriptPath,"",$requestURL);
$requestParts = explode("/", $requestURL);
echo $requestURL;
```

This should output the components of the URL that is requested by my web service and should split it into its components. But whatever URL I try: I always get the result: /index.php

but there should be the components requested with the URL I think be shown?

Comment: I believe you should use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI']` to get original URI.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I just got the answer by accident:
By switch REDIRECT_URL to REQUEST_URI in the code, I got the correct output.